# How many publications to list as "selected"?

Tags: publications, application, computer-science, cv, faculty-application

I'm applying for CS tenure track positions this year, and was advised to add a "Selected Publications" part to my CV (out of 20+ conference and journal papers). How long should this section be? Can I pick all my top-tier publications (seven) or do I need to select among them?

Comment: Are you the primary author on all of these?

Comment: @BryanKrause - depends on your definition of primary. All papers are in alphabetical order; in some I contributed more than my fair share and in some less.

Comment: In my field one would typically emphasize the papers they contributed most to rather than the highest-tier (though you might slip some of those in, too, depending on the contribution and nature of the paper); although, in my field, this is typically also indicated by first or last authorship, so I'm not sure how exactly to treat it in yours.

Comment: My gut instinct says no more than 10, but I'm not in your field.

Comment: Ask the search committee!

Answer (score 2):

I would certainly include them all (the seven). Even more than the seven top tier ones. If you were an old hand in academia with hundreds, then you select. A young starter-upper should include a much larger fraction of the published work.

Don't neglect that in CS, conferences are usually primary.

But seven seems too few if you have more than 20.

Comment: If I include all second-tier and up publications, is it still "Selected"? It becomes all papers but a handful. What would you consider a reasonable fraction of the overall?

Comment: Like I said, I think "selected" is intended for those with a much more extensive list. What fits on a page? Most, I'd guess.

Comment: I see. I think the tip was to write "selected" publications, *followed by the remaining ones*, to make them stand out. Then I agree it's good to list all of them. Would you split the papers into "selected" and others, or just put everything chronographically?